# WP: получить все записи, а потом разбить их по рубрикам и вывести

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть произвольный тип постов (допустим post-type = articles (со своей таксономией), нужно построить меню вида

- Категория 1

  - Запись 1 от категории 1
  - Запись 2 от категории 1
  - Запись 3 от категории 1
- Категория 2

  - Запись 1 от категории 2
  - Запись 2 от категории 2
  - Запись 3 от категории 2

и т.д.

В интернете есть варианты, когда цикл строится так: сначала получаем категории через get_categories (или get_terms), а потом уже получаем записи каждой из полученных категорий.

Проблема данного метода в том, что делает 2 дополнительных запроса к БД для получения списка категорий.

Можно ли просто сначала получить список всех записей данного типа, а потом уже разбить их, исходя из того, в какие категории записи входят, воспользовавшись функцией `get_the_category()` (она вроде не делает доп запросов в БД, т.к. данные содержатся уже в полученной записи)?

Answer (score 2):

Не надо ломать себе голову насчёт лишних запросов к базе. WordPress достаточно хорошо кеширован внутри - за вас уже сделали всю работу.

get_the_category() работает через get_terms(), а в ней используется кеширование. Вот код get_the_terms().

```
function get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( ! $post = get_post( $post ) )
        return false;

    $terms = get_object_term_cache( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
    if ( false === $terms ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            $term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
            wp_cache_add( $post->ID, $term_ids, $taxonomy . '_relationships' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filters the list of terms attached to the given post.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param array|WP_Error $terms    List of attached terms, or WP_Error on failure.
     * @param int            $post_id  Post ID.
     * @param string         $taxonomy Name of the taxonomy.
     */
    $terms = apply_filters( 'get_the_terms', $terms, $post->ID, $taxonomy );

    if ( empty( $terms ) )
        return false;

    return $terms;
}
```

Как видите, выполнение начинается с проверки результатов вашего запроса в кеше.

Comment: запросы к БД смотрю при помощи `<?php echo get_num_queries (); ?>` Например, если построить просто цикл WP_Query для вывода постов, то происходит 3 запроса. А если взять такой вот вариант реализации https://wordimpress.com/loop-through-categories-and-display-posts-within/ то у меня 15 запросов уже.

Comment: Там тоже все кешируется на уровне mySQL. Поверьте, 15 запросов к базе - это ни о чем. Можно, конечно, и одним запросом вытянуть все ваше меню, а потом пройтись по постам и разнести их в нужные категории. Выбирать вам - что важнее: скорость разработки или экономия миллисекунд времени выполнения, которую никто не заметит.

Comment: Хотелось бы конечно увидеть вариант с экономией, в образовательных целях, ну да ладно. Благодарю за ответ. У меня есть ещё вопрос, связанный с циклом, который решить не могу. Сейчас создам ещё один вопрос.